# How can I call R shiny html file via javascript?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to make a very simple password protection for an R shiny web app file. The code you see below is contained in an index.html. Within that same folder is a file named "testflex.html". That is the file i want to protect with a password. Nothing happens when I enter the username and password. However, when I enter WRONG username or password the error message is displayed.

Any hints? (Code is below)

```
    function showPass(form){

        var user = form.username.value;
        var pass = form.pwd.value;

        var user1 = "admin" // this is the username
        var pass1 = "abcd1234" // this is the password

        if(user === user1 && pass === pass1){

            window.open = "testflex.html";

        }

        else{
            document.write("Wrong password or username");
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>

  <form>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" /> <br />
      <input type="button" value="Log In" onclick="showPass(form)" />   </form> </body>
```

Comment: add ; after user1,pass1 and try to use == instead of ===

Comment: I see that I have a couple of mistakes in the code but regardless the solution does not work... Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. 
Concerning your question:
Use `window.open("testflex.html")` instead of `window.open = "testflex.html";` 
This works for me:

```
library(shiny)

openWindow <- '
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("resetValue", function(message) {
  window.open("new.html");
});
'

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML(openWindow))),
      selectInput("open", "Class Type:", c(FALSE, TRUE))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("class")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  global <- reactiveValues(sample = 1:9)

  observe({
    if(input$open){
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "keyVal")
    }
  })

  output$class <- renderText({
    print(input$open)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I should be able to handle this from within the shiny app script itself. Will look at it tonight when i get back from home.

Comment: No actually it did not... Browser will not accept that javescript can open other files on a server...

Comment: ah too bad. Hmm another idea would be to try via R: `browseURL()` ?

Comment: Thx. Will try it. I have  tryed to use apache2. (https://www.r-bloggers.com/password-protect-shiny-apps/). I have managed to get apache server pasword working, but cannot get R Shiny apps to run as well.

Comment: No it did not work either... Ideas are still welcome.